# Why connection get timed out when i connect to my MTA server?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I just created a ubuntu 20.04 LTS AWS ec2 instance and installed a MTA server on it. Everything works well and the console also shows the server is running correctly. But when I try to connect to my server through MTA it shows connection timed out. I don't know how to resolve it. Please Help !

Answer (score 0):

Usually timed out connections are related to Security Groups not being properly configured, this is an example taking in consideration SSH connection issues, but you can relate. Just make sure you have proper SG rules for the port(s) you're trying to connect to:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-resolve-ssh-connection-errors/

Comment: Yeah I have created proper Sg rules but tje problem ramains.

Comment: You should provide more details, otherwise it's just guessing.